# blueimp jquery fileupload progress for individual files

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, file-upload, blueimp

I have a problem trying to figure out how to report individual files upload progress when sending a selection of files within one request.

The progress event data doesn't seem to contain any pointer to a specific file that is being uploaded.

This is the code that I am using:

```
$('#fileupload')
.fileupload({
    dataType: "json",
    singleFileUploads: false, //to ensure that all files are in one request
    url: "/api/files/upload",
    progressInterval: 100,
    add: function(e, data) {
        $('#filelistholder').removeClass('hide');
        $(data.files)
            .each(function(index) {
                data.context = $('<div />').text(data.files[index].name).appendTo('#filelistholder');
                $('</div><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"  style="width:0%"></div></div>').appendTo(data.context);
            });
        $('#btnUploadAll').click(function() {
                data.submit();
            });
    },
    progress: function(e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        //how to get progress for a current file?
    },
    processalways: { //process does not get called at all...
        function(e, data) {
            console.log('Process ' + data.files[data.index].name + ' ended.');
        }
    }
});
```

The controller action returns as follows

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        var result = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray();

        foreach (HttpContent content in uploadProvider.Contents)
        {
            var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            repository.SaveFile(stream, content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"",""));
            dynamic fileObj = new JObject();
            fileObj.name = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
            result.Add(fileObj);
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        return this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

I also had a look at some of the related questions here on SO, such as 
[Blueimp file upload, how do you know which file the progress callback is for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708580/blueimp-file-upload-how-do-you-know-which-file-the-progress-callback-is-for)
but I failed to find any answer

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've answered this in the question you linked to.